# How to dynamically change attribute of an xml node with c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, xml-attribute

I have a c# application that saves user's data to an xml document.  I want to be able to dynamically change the attribute of an xml node based on a user entering different criteria into a text box and choosing to save/overwrite the existing file save.  The problem is that I can't simply delete the node and recreate it with the new attribute as the node has child nodes that can't be deleted.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

the XmlNode.Attributes method does not provide a way as I can tell to delte just the attribute of a node and reassign it.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: Start by using XDocument, not XmlDocument. Unless you're still using Fx 2.

Comment: It is too late for me to stop using XmlDocument.  I have done way too much with it already.  Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Have it your way. `XAttribute.Value` is simply writeable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cast your node to an XmlElement and use the `element.SetAttribute(...);` method.

```
((XmlElement)node).SetAttribute("name", "value");
```

Also I believe there is a way to do it without the cast if you know the attribute already exists:

```
node.Attributes["name"].Value = "value";
```

Comment: SetAttribute works even if the attribute isn't present